# WinAPI AttachConsole?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code and I'm not sure if it should be `== TRUE` or `!= FALSE`.

This is the code now:

```
void AttachConsole() {
    bool has_console = ::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) == TRUE;

    if (!has_console) {
        // We weren't launched from a console, so just return.
        // We could alloc our own console, but meh:
        // has_console = AllocConsole() == TRUE;
        has_console_attached_ = false;

        return;
    }

    has_console_attached_ = true;
}
```

I think it should be `!= FALSE` but I'm not sure?

Comment: in windows, `TRUE` is 1 and `FALSE` is 0, so both ways that you are thinking of are the same

Comment: `TRUE` may be 1, but most `BOOL` functions are documented as returning non-zero on success, not 1 specifically, so best to use `!= FALSE`. In this case, any non-zero value will convert to `true` when assigned to a `bool`, so don't even compare the value at all, like Jerry's answer shows.

Comment: @ThomasMccaffery: do you do realize this example function can be reduced to a single line of code? `void AttachConsole() { has_console_attached_ = ::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS); }`

Comment: No I didn't realize that, so I can replace the code with this:

Comment: So I just need that instead? of this code void AttachConsole() {
  bool has_console = ::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
  if (!has_console) {
    // We weren't launched from a console, so just return.
    // We could alloc our own console, but meh:
    // has_console = AllocConsole() == TRUE;
    has_console_attached_ = false;
    return;
  }
  has_console_attached_ = true;

Answer (score 3):

The return value is documented only as being 0 for failure or non-zero for success.

So yes, you could use `!= FALSE` or you could just use:

```
bool has_console = ::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
```

The conversion from BOOL (really an integer) to `bool` will convert 0 to `false`, and anything else to `true`--exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah I was confused because I used an analyzer and said should be != FALSE. Thanks for clearing that up. In fact I can remove the == TRUE and will work the same.